# Jmeter beanshell classnotfounderror

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to use beanshell on jmeter (last version), but everytime I add a beanshell processor (pre, pro or whatever), I got this error

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter
```

Ubuntu last stable versione, jmeter last stable version(2.13)
I don't understand what I need to do..

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: here full logs:

2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_IE  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /home/asada/Downloads/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/user.properties  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /home/asada/Downloads/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/system.properties  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2012 The Apache Software Foundation  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.8.20130705  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_72  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=3.19.0-49-generic  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO 
- jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (Ireland)  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (Ireland)  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/usr/share/jmeter  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir 
=/home/asada/Downloads/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD
=/home/asada/Downloads/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 127.0.1.1 Name: asada-Precision-WorkStation-T5500 FullName: asada-Precision-WorkStation-T5500  2016/03/02 14:44:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties  2016/03/02 14:44:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'  2016/03/02 14:44:06 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'  2016/03/02 14:44:07 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform]  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is   2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is   2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is   2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Reuse SSL session context on subsequent iterations: true  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true  2016/03/02 14:44:08 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000  2016/03/02 14:44:24 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Beanshell Interpreter not found  2016/03/02 14:44:24 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter  2016/03/02 14:44:29 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter  2016/03/02 14:44:29 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter  2016/03/02 14:44:29 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Listeners will be started after enabling running version  2016/03/02 14:44:29 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false  2016/03/02 14:44:29 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 2016/03/02 14:44:29 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*)  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO 
- jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see jmeter.properties)  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Running PostProcessors in forward order  2016/03/02 14:44:30 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter  2016/03/02 14:44:30 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/home/asada/Downloads/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin'  2016/03/02 14:44:30 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)

Answer (score 4):

Double check your JMeter installation, it should contain `bsh-2.0b5.jar`. If it doesn't - download it from i.e. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b5/bsh-2.0b5.jar and drop to /lib folder of your JMeter installation. If you installed it from Ubuntu repositories it can be something like `/usr/share/jmeter/lib/`

Just in case take the following steps:

1. Create a new Ubuntu user and log into its account.
2. Download the latest version of [Oracle Java Server JRE or JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) an unpack it somewhere
3. Set `JAVA_HOME` system variable pointing to Java installation folder and add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to `PATH` variable like:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/opt/java && export JAVA_HOME
   PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH && export PATH
   ```
4. Download JMeter 2.13 (or newer) and unpack it somewhere
5. In the same terminal window you set JAVA_HOME and PATH navigate to /bin folder of your JMeter installation and type `./jmeter`

If the problem still persists - post full *jmeter.log* file contents here.

If there will be nothing suspicious in the jmeter.log file - add

[debug();](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

line at the beginning of your Beanshell script and inspect terminal output.

Comment: I checked for bsh-2.0b5.jar and there is that jar in lib dir. For the other question I answered you with full logs.. Let me know

Comment: `JMeterHome=/usr/share/jmeter` - I guess the problem is in this variable

Comment: Ok, Do you know where Can I change it? I just downloaded jmeter and extract in a dir..that's all I did. I also install an older version with sudo apt-get install jmeter but the same issue

Comment: I just did a grep and I found that field on this: ./bin/jmeter.log
./docs/api/index-all.html
./docs/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html .....

Comment: jmeter -d=/home/myhome/Downloads/apache-jmeter-2.13/
there are still the same errors

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar issue. It could be due to your `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS`.

Remove that, Relaunch everything and Try again.

---

1. Close the terminal
2. ReLaunch the terminal
3. type jmeter  (or ./jmeter)and hit enter

Now - What do you see in the Terminal once jmeter is launched?

Comment: where should I remove that?

Comment: I just tried to put in .bashrc file this line: unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS but it doesn't work

Comment: @Danko, Can you do the above steps in the updated answer?

Comment: I did a lot of time, no results...where can I unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS ?

Comment: What do you see in the Terminal once jmeter is launched?

Comment: what i am asking will not be there in the log. it should be there in the terminal.

Comment: in the termal I don't see anything. but in right above I can see the symbol with 2 errors

Answer (score 0):

Now It works.

With windows I never had a single problem.
BTW I did:

1. sudo apt-get remove jmeter
2. delete the folder where I had the second jmeter in my pc.
3. I update the java alternatives and I choose the
   java 8 with both commands: sudo update-alternatives --config java
   sudo update-alternatives --config javac
4. Restart the pc
5. Download again jmeter
6. this time I moved the dir on  /opt/apache-jmeter-2.13.
7. I went in bin and I just ran ./jmeter.

This time without errors. I really don't know what was the problem.